Why is תא שמע used for both Attempted Challenges & Proofs?
Why does the Gemara use תא שמע for both Attempted Challenges & Attempted Proofs?
It can get especially confusing.
Take Bava Basra 94b-95a for example, which is discussing Rav Huna of the previous Amud:

1st תא שמע is Attempted Challenge
2nd is Attempted Proof
3rd is Attempted Proof
4th is Attempted Challenge
5th is Attempted Proof
6th is Attempted Proof
7th is Attempted Proof

While obviously one can use logic to figure out which one it is,
my question is why is there no specific term for each?

תא שמע is essentially a proof. It's just a proof in either direction.

Good question but like Yehuda said, a challenge for one person is a proof for another. So it really means just proof

According to "Talmudic Terminology" by R. Nosson Dovid Rabinowich the expression תא שמע can have 3 different uses:

To show that a Memra, a reported teaching, opinion or decision of the Amoraim, is in conflict with a Mishna or Baraisa (i.e. a Tannaic statement).
To provide a solution to a problem בעיה.
To introduce an argument or difficulty.

The reason, why there are such different uses, is explained in the Practical Talmudic Dictionary by R. Yitzchak Frank: the expression תא שמע introduces  a mishna, a baraitha, a pasuk, or an early amora's statement or practice that is quoted. The usage of the quote itself can serve a a proof for the opinion of an amora, or as a resolution to a problem, or as a basis for argument or difficulty.
According to both R. Frank and R. Rabinowich, as a refutation תא שמע slightly differs from מיתיבי. The word מיתיבי is only used synonymosly to introduce a refutation (תיובתא) of an amoraic statement based on higher authority of undisputed Mishna or Baraitha. Thus it does not have a flavor of a possibility that an argument may continue. I.e. מיתיבי is a more certain clause, while תא שמע leaves open the possibility that a discussion will continue.

But if it's just means a quote, why use the same term? מיתיבי is also a quote (from a ברייתא), but it's exclusively used as a Q?

@user907a according to both R. Frank and R. Rabinowich, מיתיבי is used synonymosly only as a refutation (תיובתא) of an amoraic statement based on higher authority of undisputed Mishna or Baraitha, but does not have a flavor of an argument may continue. I.e. it is a more certain.

These sources confirm the OPs intuition that the phrase is non specific, but it doesn't answer why that should be so

In plain translation, it means "come and hear". It invites the reader to compare the coming cites and see if it brings proof to the question posed one way or another. It is part of the "shakla V'tarya" way of teaching that the Gemara is famous for. Literally, it means "taking and throwing". It invites scrutiny, examination, discourse, questions and answers, splitting hairs, finding distinctions, finding supporting analogies, etc. That way of thinking  has been admired by the non Talmudic world as being responsible for Jewish brains, acumen, and overall "out of the box" thinking.
